# qt : How can I minimize qsplitter's child?

Tags: qt, qsplitter

[image: QSplitter]

I made a QSplitter layout. And under QSplitter, there is QWidget and it's gridLayout children. At this case, I can't minimize QSplitter to 0 size. As I see above, it has restriction for height.  What cause this problem?  I tested some cases, and I found that when I use QGridLayout for QWidget's children. But I can't set minimum height to 0.

Comment: Did you try [childrenCollapsible](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html#childrenCollapsible-prop) property?

Comment: @graphite Oh! If I turn "childrenCollapsible" on, I can move the hanldler upto the top. But I still have a problem. If cursor is on contents while dragging, handler is not moved, and on the edge it can hide finally. How can I move the handler smoothly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you can always call hide on a widget.

Comment: I found that. I use sizePolicy to "ignored", so it can be a not limited height or width